# Self-check by md5 sum during compiling

Tags: pdftex

I'm trying to make a self-check in the tex file to be sure nobody changed it. I can check the size, say `\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilesize{\jobname.tex}}{31571}`, but it happens too often that the size of the changed file is the same. Therefore I'm trying to do the checksum. Obviously something like this `\pdfstrcmp{\pdfmdfivesum file {\jobname.tex}}{d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e}` will not work.

Therefore the question: how can I get the md5 of all text *except* the md5 itself?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I would recommend using Version Control (e.g. Git) instead. If someone wants to maliciously change the file, couldn't they just edit the self-check line to be consistent with their changes?

Comment: If you include md5 in md5-ied text obviously it does. Therefore I look for a possibility not to include. Git is not an option. I can share tex file only, not even a sty file (collaborators dont want to learn something new)